# Reading from InputStream until double quotation marks

Tags: java, byte, inputstream, quotes

Need help reading from InputStream to a list of bytes until quotation marks.
The problem is, InputStream reads bytes and I'm not sure how to stop it reading when it reaches quotation marks ... I thought about something like this:

```
public static List<Byte> getQuoted(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    int c;
    LinkedList<Byte> myList = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
    while ((in.read()) != "\"") {   ?????
        list.add(c)
    .....
```

The while condition is a problem, of course the quotation marks are `String` while `int` is expected.

Comment: An `InputStream` can't contain quotation marks. `InputStream`s deal in *bytes*, and quotation marks are *characters*. You need to work out whether you're dealing with binary data or character data. If you're dealing with character data, you should be using a `Reader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\""` is a String. If you want just the character representation of `"`, use `'"'` instead.

Note that your code **will not work as you expect if your file is not in ASCII format** (and the behaviour will be inconsistent between different character sets) (it does of course depend what you expect).

If in ASCII, each character will take up a single byte in the file and [`InputStream::read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) reads a single byte (thus a single ASCII character) so everything will work fine.

If in a character set that takes up more than 1 byte per character (e.g. Unicode), each read will read less than a single character and your code will probably not work as expected.

[`Reader::read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29) (and using `Character` rather than `Byte`) is advised since it will read a character, not just a byte.

Also, you're missing an assignment:

```
while ((in.read()) != '"')
```

should be

```
while ((c = in.read()) != '"')
```

Comment: @user2177334 Remember to [upvote and/or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) this answer if you found it helpful.